# iOS / Xcode localization afterwards

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I had to develop a prototype for a customer and since we had very few time, I decided to just support one language and not to use .strings-files for localization, because I thought it could be done easily afterwards.
I'm sure in the past there was a tool integrated in Xcode to find all strings in the project and add them to a .strings-file.

I can't find such a tool. I searched the web and couldn't find any evidence that the tool did ever exist.

I want to extract all strings in .swift files into a .strings-file and replace them with the NSLocalizedString call. Does anyone know a tool to archive that? Or should I simply write a shell script to archive that. I can't believe that there is no such tool and I don't want to invent the wheel a second time.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about such a tool for strings in code (but it would be great !). Nevertheless, you can do that for storyboards and xibs.

Just select your storyboard/xib, go to File Inspector. In the Localization part, you can tick the language you want. Then, it will create a `.string` file with all text used in storyboard.

If no language appear in this part, you have to change values of `Localization native development region` in `Info` of your project.

Comment: Thank you, but i already knew the part with the storyboards. I guess I'll write a short shell script and post it here later.

Comment: Could be really great !